# Trying to filter input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am trying to filter input so not only does it get filtered when the exact input is put in but also if there are words that follow or if there is a space or something.

Current simplified code:

```
profanity = ["rude", "words"]

userInput = input(" : ")
if userInput in (profanity):
    inputLength = len(userInput)
    userInput = ""
    for i in range(inputLength):
        userInput += "*"
print (userInput)
```

So in this example, it will work with `"rude"` and `"word"`, but does not work for cases such as `"rude "` and `"rude %"`, `%` being any word/sentence. The list itself is 127 items long.

Comment: how about `prude`, `crude`, `rude weather`, etc...

Comment: This code doesn't work for me

Comment: @Bazingaa thats very strange. I ran that code before and just now again. It works by itself.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque yes I would like it to work with any text that contains a word from the list, as words on the list are profound so I made them PG for the purpose of the post. I'd want it to work with "crudeb", "rrude", "rude dude", "srudes", any input that even partly contains a whole word from the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1./ FIRST case:** you want to censor rude as **** but NOT crude as c****

The issue is that you are testing your whole input string when you actually want to work on sub strings (or even more specifically tokens since pour probably want to keep items such as `crude`)

The basic idea would be to tokenize your input string and validate each work independently. A very basic way to do so (if you don't want to dig into more advances NLP techniques) is to split over spaces.

You can try this:

```
profanity = ["rude", "words"]

userInput = input(" : ")
parts = userInput.split()
output = []
for p in parts:
    if p in profanity:
        output.append('*' * len(p))
    else:
        output.append(p)
print(' '.join(output))
```

remember this is some basic code you can improve. It won't handle cases with punctuation (`rude.`) or different case (`RUDE`)

**2./ Second Case:** you want to censor rude as **** AND crude as c****

if you want to replace any instance of rude (even in crude or any other) you can use a reverse approach

```
profanity = ["rude", "words"]

userInput = input(" : ")
for p in profanity:
    if p in userInput:
        userInput = userInput.replace(p, '*' * len(p))
print(userInput)
```

*Anyway this is a basic idea for both approaches/objectives and there is room for a lot of improvement (punctuation, caps, expressions, more advanced NLP...)*

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm new to filtering so really appreciate the help :)  method 2 is what I was looking for

Comment: @Kitem4n you're welcome! There are other ways that maybe are more flexible for approach 2 (maybe regex etc...) but for the exact task you asked this approach is rather simple and straightforward

Comment: Yes it is very simple and gets the job done. Thank you :) It's for an online kids game so can't have people finding ways around that, obviously people can still swap letters but that would just need more items to be added to the list to tackle that so thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_function(input):
    words_to_be_filtered = ["rude", "words"]
    searched = map(lambda x: x in input, words_to_be_filtered)
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x or y, searched, False)

inputs = ["something", "somethingrude", "sometwordshing"]
print(filter(filter_function, inputs))
```

Function above gives the following result : `['somethingrude', 'sometwordshing']`. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Upon the first run it worked as you said it should but when I added one more string it started to say '<filter object at 0x107773e10>' and when i removed the string to how it originally was it stayed printing the filter object message

Comment: in my computer it works independent from the size of the input. Can you share more information? Looks like you are trying to print the filter object.

Comment: Except for changing the contents of inputs by adding ", 'rude boy', 'rude.' - I changed nothing. I am running it using Python 3.7 in Mac Terminal

Comment: I changed the input to  ["something", "somethingrude", "sometwordshing",  "rude boy", "rude."], it still works for me.

Comment: That's very odd, however I found a working alternative. Thank you anyways.